# Proving $p\implies q$

Tags: logic

My teacher claims that when proving $p\implies q$ we must prove $\neg p$. But when $p$ is true and $q$ is true, $p\implies q$ but $\neg p$ is false. Am I insane?

Comment: I think what was meant was to say that proving $p\implies q$ amounts to proving $\neg q \implies \neg p$. But you don't necessarily have to use that method, sometimes proving it directly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood your teacher. *One* way to prove $p\implies q$ is to *assume* $\lnot q$ and from that assumption prove $\lnot p$. This is called proof by contraposition. (The contrapositive of $p\implies q$ is $\lnot q\implies\lnot p$.)

Of course, that is not the *only* way to prove $p\implies q$. You could also give a *direct* proof: assume $p$ and from it deduce $q$.

Comment: No, it was a multiple choice question(true/false) "to prove $p\implies q$ by contrapostition, we must show $\neg p$" I wasn't misunderstanding it.

Comment: @XVD: The statement "If $p$, then $q$" is logically equivalent to "If not $q$, then not $p$." You wonder in your question how we could "prove $\lnot p$" in the case where you assume $p$ and $q$ are both true. But a proof by contraposition of "If $p$, then $q$" does not prove $\lnot p$, tout court; it proves that $\lnot p$ *under the assumption* that $\lnot q$. And from the falsehood $\lnot q$ anything follows, including the falsehood $\lnot p$. (It would have been better for the teacher to write "To prove $p\implies q$ by contraposition, we must **assume $\lnot q$** and show $\lnot p$.)

Comment: Indeed, to "to prove $p\to q$ by contrapostition, we must show $\neg p$" is correct, *although* misleading, since showing $\neg p$ is necessary, *but not sufficient*, to prove $p\to q$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: actually, showing (the unconditional statement) $\lnot p$ *is* sufficient to prove $p\rightarrow q$. That's because $\lnot p\rightarrow(p\rightarrow q)$ is a tautology. You got it backwards: showing (i.e. proving) $\lnot p$ is sufficient, *but not necessary*, to prove $p\rightarrow q$. Right? But yes, agreed: the teacher's statement is misleading. I suspect it is elliptical for "we must *assume* $\lnot q$ and show $\lnot p$."

Comment: @XVD That is a tricky multiple choice question. It is partly true. You must first assume that that $q$ is false, i.e. that $\neg q$ is true. THEN you must must show $\neg p$ is true. I would have answered, true. If the "correct" answer is false, I would appeal it.

Answer (score 0):

you can prove as well $p\land \neg q$ is false (called : proof by contradiction)